# Flume - Delete from HDFS

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am able to view files on HDFS placed there by a Flume application -

```
sudo -u flume hadoop fs -cat tweets/2015/05/06/15/FlumeData.1430952817762
```

but when I try to delete the above folder, tweets, and all it's contents -

```
sudo -u flume hadoop fs -rm -r tweets
```

I get this error -

```
Failed to move to trash: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/flume/tweets: Permission denied: user=flume, access=WRITE, inode="/user/flume":cloudera:flume:drwxr-xr-x
```

I know I need to have WRITE permission, probably using CHMOD in some way, but i'm not sure what user can do it. Of course, user HDFS cannot see the folder -

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 tweets
chmod: `tweets': No such file or directory
```

How can I get access to delete those Flume created HDFS files? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think if you want to change the permissions of the `tweets` folder as the `hdfs` user, you must specify the complete path, i.e. `/user/flume/tweets`, otherwise the system will try to find such a folder under the `hdfs` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

When deleting a file with the `hadoop fs -rm` command but without the `-skipTrash` option, the file will be moved to the `.Trash` directory under the HDFS home directory of the acting user. In your case, the user is `flume`, which would mean the home directory of it on HDFS would be `/user/flume` and the trash directory being `/user/flume/.Trash`.

Per your observed error, the home directory of `flume` user is not owned by it, causing the issue: `inode="/user/flume":cloudera:flume:drwxr-xr-x`

To therefore resolve the issue, ensure the `flume` user is made as the true owner of its `/user/flume` HDFS home directory via: `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown flume /user/flume`.